# How can I automatically parse tables spanning over multiple pages with Python

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-table, threadpool

I want to parse a table (or multiple tables) spanning over several pages.
The way I did it below works but is is way too manual, and I would like it to automatically parse the tables from the different pages and combine them into one. The number of pages might not always be the same.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

one = "https://rittresultater.no/nb/sb_tid/923?page=0&pv2=11027&pv1=U"
two = "https://rittresultater.no/nb/sb_tid/923?page=1&pv2=11027&pv1=U"
three = "https://rittresultater.no/nb/sb_tid/923?page=2&pv2=11027&pv1=U"

#parse the first page
html = urlopen(one)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
table = soup.find_all(class_="table-condensed")
one = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]

#parse the second page
html = urlopen(two)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
table = soup.find_all(class_="table-condensed")
two = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]

#parse thr third page
html = urlopen(three)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
table = soup.find_all(class_="table-condensed")
three = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]

df = pd.concat([one,two,three], axis = 0)
df
```

Notice that the urls only differ in "page=X". Also the webpage itself contain links to eg. next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
results = {}
for page_num in range(1, 10): #change depending on max page
    address = 'https://rittresultater.no/nb/sb_tid/923?page=' + \
               str(page_num) + '&pv2=11027&pv1=U' 

    html = urlopen(address)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find_all(class='table-condensed')
    output = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    results[page_num] = output
```

When its done use a list comprehension to do relevent thing to output, if it's the last line in your code but scaled up do this:

```
df = pd.concat([v for v in results.values()], axis = 0)
```